# How to check for a SPECIFIC object and that specific object being the ONLY object in a better way then index approach used below?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, frontend

I want to check it the `taskDetails` object exclusively and Only has `lastTask` value and no other.(no other values apart from lastTask)

So I am checking with the `[0]index` approach as below;

```
Object.keys(this.clubdetails.taskDetails)[0]==["lastTask"]
```

I doubt this because, if another object "currentTask" gets added at index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m092X.png), still the index of lastTask remains ["0"] and my check about lastTask at index[0]returns true but the condition of Only lastTask value being present in taskDetails object goes false.

I believe there should be a better way to check if object has only a specific value and no other, please advice on the same.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the length of object keys is 1:

```
Object.keys(this.clubdetails.taskDetails).length === 1 && Object.keys(this.clubdetails.taskDetails)[0]==="lastTask"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.stringify(Object.keys(this.clubdetails.taskDetails)) === JSON.stringify(["lastTask"])
```

The idea is convert the `Object.keys(this.clubdetails.taskDetails)` to string. If it only have key **lastTask** only,  the converted string should become `["lastTask"]`

Comment: Yes, thats perfect. thank you very much for your answer and advice sir, Accepting Igor's answer as his reputation is less.